# JpaTransactionManager crash without error during spring startup

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, jpa

I'm using Hibernate to connect to an AWS Aurora cluster from my spring-based web app. 
When I'm running it locally and in TEST env everything is working, but in PROD environment the web app crashes without any error. Since both environments use the same configs in relation to hibernate / DB connection, I suspect a maven dependency issue or some odd misconfiguration in Spring.

Tried to delete m2 cache from build machines as well, didn't help.

Logs from app:

```
INFO  2019-06-14 04:14:23.173 UTC message="Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5391 ms" 
INFO  2019-06-14 04:14:24.590 UTC message="Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1992eaf4: startup date [Fri Jun 14 04:14:17 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy" 
INFO  2019-06-14 04:14:24.883 UTC message="Initializing connection to Aurora DB with url="jdbc:mysql://*****.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/****?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL", username="****", driverClassName="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"" 
INFO  2019-06-14 04:14:24.951 UTC message="Connection to Aurora DB initialized successfully with url="jdbc:mysql://******.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/****?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL", username="****"" 
INFO  2019-06-14 04:14:25.120 UTC message="LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean initialized successfully." 
INFO  2019-06-14 04:14:25.209 UTC message="Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'" 
INFO  2019-06-14 04:14:25.274 UTC message="HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]" 
INFO  2019-06-14 04:14:25.513 UTC message="HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.2.Final}" 
WARN  2019-06-14 04:14:25.779 UTC message="HHH020100: The Ehcache second-level cache provider for Hibernate is deprecated.  See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12441 for details." 
INFO  2019-06-14 04:14:25.807 UTC message="HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}"
```

App just crashes afterwards, no additional info / exceptions.

**Configuration**

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateConfiguration.class);

    @Value("${data.hibernate.verbose:true}")
    private boolean hibernateShowSql;

    @Value("${data.hibernate.packagesToScan:com.myapp}")
    private String packagesToScan;

    @Value("${data.hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;

    @Value("${data.hibernate.cache.secondLevel.enable:true}")
    private boolean enableSecondLevelCache;

    @Value("${data.hibernate.cache.query.enable:true}")
    private boolean enableQueryLevelCache;

    @Value("${data.hibernate.cache.class:org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory}")
    private String cacheFactoryClass;

    @Value("${myapp.datasource.url:null}")
    private String dbUrl;

    @Value("${myapp.datasource.username:null}")
    private String dbUsername;

    @Value("${myapp.datasource.password:null}")
    private String dbPassword;

    @Value("${myapp.datasource.driverClassName:com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver}")
    private String sqlDriverClass;

    private static final String PROPERTY_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_CACHE_FACTORY_CLASS = "hibernate.cache.region.factory_class";
    private static final String PROPERTY_USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE = "hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache";
    private static final String PROPERTY_USE_QUERY_CACHE = "hibernate.cache.use_query_cache";

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        logger.info("Initializing connection to Aurora DB with url=\"{}\", username=\"{}\", driverClassName=\"{}\"", dbUrl, dbUsername, sqlDriverClass);
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(dbUrl) || StringUtils.isBlank(dbUsername) || StringUtils.isBlank(dbPassword)) {
            logger.error("SEVERE misconfiguration in connection to DB url=\"{}\", username=\"{}\" passwordIsBlank={}", dbUrl, dbUsername, StringUtils.isBlank(dbPassword));
        }
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(dbUrl)
                .username(dbUsername)
                .password(dbPassword)
                .driverClassName(sqlDriverClass)
                .build();
        logger.info("Connection to Aurora DB initialized successfully with url=\"{}\", username=\"{}\"", dbUrl, dbUsername);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        logger.info("JpaTransactionManager initialized successfully.");
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdaptor());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(packagesToScan.split(","));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaHibernateProperties());
        logger.info("LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean initialized successfully.");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public HibernateConnection hibernateConnection() {
        HibernateConnection hibernateConnection = new HibernateConnection(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject().createEntityManager());
        logger.info("HibernateConnection initialized successfully.");
        return hibernateConnection;
    }

    private HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdaptor() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }

    private Properties jpaHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_SHOW_SQL, hibernateShowSql);
        properties.put(PROPERTY_DIALECT, hibernateDialect);
        properties.put(PROPERTY_CACHE_FACTORY_CLASS, cacheFactoryClass);
        properties.put(PROPERTY_USE_QUERY_CACHE, enableQueryLevelCache);
        properties.put(PROPERTY_USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, enableSecondLevelCache);
        return properties;
    }

}
```

**POM:**

```
        <properties>
            <dependency.version.mfa-core-service>0.3.7</dependency.version.mfa-core-service>
            <dependency.version.spring-orm>4.3.7.RELEASE</dependency.version.spring-orm>
            <dependency.version.mysql-connector>8.0.11</dependency.version.mysql-connector>
            <dependency.version.hibernate>5.4.2.Final</dependency.version.hibernate>
        <dependency.version.commons-dbcp2>2.1.1</dependency.version.commons-dbcp2>
        </properties>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.version.spring-orm}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.version.mysql-connector}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.version.hibernate}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>${dependency.version.commons-dbcp2}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Usage:**

```
public class HibernateConnection {

    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public HibernateConnection(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
    ....
}
```

Edit:
I enabled DEBUG. On PROD env I get these logs just before the crash:

```
DEBUG 2019-06-14 05:48:48.487 UTC message="Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [sequence-identity] -> [org.hibernate.id.SequenceIdentityGenerator]" 
DEBUG 2019-06-14 05:48:48.487 UTC message="Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-sequence] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator]" 
DEBUG 2019-06-14 05:48:48.489 UTC message="Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-table] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator]"
```

While in TEST env I the startup continues and I get these logs:

```
DEBUG 2019-06-14 05:25:34.502 UTC message="Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [sequence-identity] -> [org.hibernate.id.SequenceIdentityGenerator]" 
DEBUG 2019-06-14 05:25:34.502 UTC message="Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-sequence] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator]" 
DEBUG 2019-06-14 05:25:34.516 UTC message="Registering IdentifierGenerator strategy [enhanced-table] -> [org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator]" 
Fri Jun 14 05:25:37 UTC 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Fri Jun 14 05:25:43 UTC 2019 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
DEBUG 2019-06-14 05:25:46.563 UTC message="Database ->
           name : MySQL
        version : 5.7.12
          major : 5
          minor : 7" 
DEBUG 2019-06-14 05:25:46.563 UTC message="Driver ->
           name : MySQL Connector/J
        version : mysql-connector-java-8.0.11 (Revision: 6d4eaa273bc181b4cf1c8ad0821a2227f116fedf)
          major : 8
          minor : 0" 
DEBUG 2019-06-14 05:25:46.563 UTC message="JDBC version : 4.2"
```

So it seems like the app crashes once connection to DB is established.

Comment: I see INFO and WARN in log, please enable TRACE to see more insights.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the URL pointed to a cluster that was configured with a security group that didn't include my server. The silent failure is problematic but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯